# What is the integral cohomology of an Enriques surface over a finite field?

Tags: cohomology, etale-cohomology, algebraic-surfaces

Probably this is well-known, but I could not find it. I would like to understand the integral $2$-adic etale cohomology of an Enriques surface over $\mathbb{F}_q$ in dimension 2: $H_{et}^2(X, \mathbb{Z}_2)$. What I am really interested in is the torsion structure, and if there are torsion elements of order greater than 2. References would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: $q$ odd? I believe the answer is pretty similar to the characteristic zero case, so no torsion of order greater than $2$...

Comment: Yes, q odd. I was thinking/hoping that there would be nothing bigger than 2, but would like a reference to be able to say for sure!

Comment: Over fields $k$ not of characteristic 2 any Enriques surface $X$ has geometric fundamental group of order 2 and $X_{\overline{k}}$ lifts to a smooth proper $W(\overline{k})$-scheme (with Enriques geometric generic fiber). Thus, by smooth and proper base change  ${\rm{H}}^j(X_{\overline{k}}, \mathbf{Z}_2)$ is "as over $\mathbf{C}$" and ${\rm{H}}^1(X_{\overline{k}}, \mathbf{Z}_2)=0$. For finite $k$, the Leray spectral sequence ${\rm{H}}^i(k, {\rm{H}}^j(X_{\overline{k}}, \mathbf{Z}_2)) \Rightarrow {\rm{H}}^{i+j}(X, \mathbf{Z}_2)$ then does the job. For references, ask Google or Christian Liedtke.

Comment: Thanks! I did ask Christian but am still waiting on that; I decided to also post here out of excitement.

Comment: A couple of his papers were among the top hits when I tried "Enriques surface, positive characteristic" in Google, the first of which was this: http://arxiv.org/abs/0912.4291  That provides some references on char-0 lifting over Witt vectors near the end.

Comment: If you are searching Google, you can also use the keywords "Cossec", "Dolgachev", and "Schoeer".